# Cpanel/CSF Firewall: Excessive resource usage notification

Tags: cpanel, whm

I am getting the following, and before I take any action I need to know if this is actually excessive resources or if i should just increase my notification threshold.

```
lfd on sv1.server.com: Excessive resource usage: tendes (3222 (Parent PID:3222))

Time:         Thu Oct 16 10:00:25 2014 -0400 Account:      tendes
Resource:     Process Time Exceeded:     64257 > 7200 (seconds)
Executable:   /usr/bin/php Command Line: /usr/bin/php PID:         
3222 (Parent PID:3222) Killed:       No
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I an see your tendes user php files are taking lot of time to execute and due to that you are getting this alert from your server firewall. You will have to check your user scrips OR add this user in /etc/csf/csf.pignore file so that you will get any alert of this user.